# UISlider selected thumb image does not persist when dragging out of the slider

Tags: swift, uikit, uislider

I have two thumb images for my slider, set in the following way:

```
seeker.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "seeker-thumb-normal"), for: .normal)
seeker.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "seeker-thumb-selected"), for: .highlighted)
```

This seems to work pretty well, except when I start dragging my UISlider, and move my finger far enough from the slider, the slider reverts the thumb image back to .normal, even though I'm still tracking. How do I keep the selected thumb image during the entire tracking event? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing `UISlider` and override `trackRect(forBounds`

```
class YourSlider: UISlider {
    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let point = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY)
        return CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: Your image width, height: your image height))
    }
}
```

and use instance of `YourSlider` instead of `UISlider` in your code. Idea shamelessly copied from this [medium article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/how-to-personalize-and-use-uislider-in-swift-ec96d2e8f99d) all credits to author